# Multiple inheritance through interface

Tags: java

Lets assume i have 2 interfaces

```
interface A {

    public static final int CONSTANT1 = 6;

}

interface B {

    public static final int CONSTANT1 = 7;
}

class MYclass implements A, B {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(CONSTANT1);//<- ??

    }
}
```

Which constant will get printed or is it compilation error?

Comment: Why not try it?

Comment: Well, the above code definitely won't compile, as you haven't declared a type for either `CONSTANT1` or `CONSTANT2`. Also, `Myclass implements interfaceA and interfaceB` will also throw a compiler error.

Comment: Is it asked to test our skill ? ;)

Comment: And also, Java is a semicolon-language.

Comment: I just gave psedocode

Comment: javac should complain that CONSTANT1 is ambiguous

Comment: @sandy - If you're asking questions about whether or not a piece of code will compile, then it would behoove you to not give us a snippet of pseudocode.

Comment: @Jack i tried out but not able to understand why this happens with java 6.I am not here to give test to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a reference, however, the code:

```
interface A
{
    int CONSTANT1 = 6;
}

interface B
{
    int CONSTANT1 = 7;
}

public class Test implements A, B
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(CONSTANT1);
    }
}
```

prints 7.

Comment: why doesn't it print 6?

Comment: @adchilds: which compiler are you using?

Comment: @VishalK $ java -version
java version "1.6.0_25"

Comment: but still why 7 and  why not 6?

Comment: @sandy, as far as I can see, it's the ordering of the interfaces that matters. Switch the order of the definitions of the interfaces, and `6` will be printed. Perhaps, someone else can better explain the correct reason, however.

Comment: @adchilds: come on this  won't compile at all...

Comment: @VishalK, I don't know what else to tell you, it does for me. And runs.

Comment: why error is 7 ans why not in 6?

Comment: @adchilds: Save this file again and recompile it using `javac -source 1.5 Test`

Comment: @VishalK, I trust that in some cases it won't compile, but in my specific case, it does. No need for me to run around trying every version of java until it doesn't work. However, the above command works: javac Test.java -source 1.5

Comment: @sandy Don't try to figure out why 7 not 6 since returning any of these values is most probably bug of 1.6.0_25 version and was corrected in Java 7 since JVM can't determine which value is better.

Answer (score 1):

my javac 7 fail on adchilds' example:

> error: reference to CONSTANT1 is ambiguous, both variable CONSTANT1 in A and variable CONSTANT1 in B match

JLS http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3

> It is possible for a class to inherit more than one field with the same name. Such a situation does not in itself cause a compile-time error. However, any attempt within the body of the class to refer to any such field by its simple name will result in a compile-time error, because such a reference is ambiguous.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.6.1

> If an expression name consists of a single Identifier, then there must be exactly one declaration denoting either a local variable, parameter, or field visible (§6.4.1) at the point at which the Identifier occurs. Otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

Comment: Sorry, I was using 1.6.0_25